# Custom Google Tag Manager gtm.elementClasses

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

I have been requested by a client to push data into gtm.elementClasses using the dataLayer.push() function. More specifically, 99% of all links on our webpage don't have classes, as they are inside of div elements with button classes and therefore elementClasses is empty.

I have found few articles talking about the stuff I think I need, but I seem to have hit a hard wall.

I would say that I could possibly use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440749/parent-class-in-google-tag-manager) for my needs, but the question I have is, how would I do so. Should it trigger on `<a>` tag click and then fill the dataLayer with appropriate data? If it is the case, how?

Until now we used just the easiest setup described [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart).

Thanks a lot for any kind of answer.

Comment: What type of information do you need to push? I understand there is no classes defined on the elements, so it isn't very clear to me what information do you need. And out of curiosity, do you necessarily have to use this approach? If it's a specific client demand I get it, but it seems overly complicated.

Comment: @GersonLCSJunior I have done more research and suggested a different approach to the client and they accepted, I found this overly complicated as well. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple - make a specific trigger in GTM and filter it there, not create custom JS functions.